# Multiple PHP IF statements; looking for a way to tighten my code

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I have a series of variables that need to take on one of two values based on a certain condition; in this case, a value pulled from a MySQL database. For simplicity, let's say the variables are $var1, $var2, $var3, etc. I have twenty variables set up like this, each attached to a form field. Right now, the logic for determining their values looks like this:

```
if($row['condition1'] == 0) //Value pulled from MySQL table {
  $var1 = $_POST['var1']; //Value from a form field
  } else {
  $var1 = $_POST['var1hidden']; //Value from a hidden field
  }

if($row['condition2'] == 0) //Value pulled from MySQL table {
  $var2 = $_POST['var2']; //Value from a form field
  } else {
  $var2 = $_POST['var2hidden']; //Value from a hidden field
  }
```

So this works, but I'd prefer not to have to copy it twenty times. Is there a way to loop through $var1-$var20, or am I stuck with this because each variable needs to be evaluated on its own?

Comment: will you always have 20 variables or does that change?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best solution would be to change your HTML form inputs into an array like structure using `name[]` syntax. That way, you can get rid of the 20 different variables and manage user input efficiently.

However, you can dynamically define and compare variables using `${ }` syntax:

```
for ($i=1; $i <= 20; $i++) { 
    if($row['condition'.$i] == 0) {
        ${'var'.$i} = $_POST['var'.$i];
    } else {
        ${'var'.$i} = $_POST['var'.$i.'hidden'];
    }
}
```

Comment: While it's a common way, I think best solution will be name variables in HTML as array (i.e. with `[]` syntax) and so get rid of 20 variables in PHP. I suggest you to mention that in your answer

Comment: So, if my variables are named CoPI1Name, CoPI2Name, etc, would my code look like this?
    for ($i=1; $i <= 20; $i++) { 
    if(isset(${'CoPI'.$i.'Name'})) {
        ${'CoPI'.$i.'Name'} = $_POST['CoPI'.$i.'Name'];
    } else {
        ${'CoPI'.$i.'Name'} = $_POST['CoPI'.$i.'hidden'];
    }
    }

Comment: Good solution Amal and i just know ${} from you, hahhaa i don't know that ... i +1 you !

Comment: @AmalMurali: Great solution. Working like a charm and it's also going to help in other parts of my form. Thanks!

Comment: @Chris: Glad to have been of help. Good luck with your project :)

Comment: +1 for `The best solution would be to change your HTML form inputs`

Answer (score 1):

i dont know if i understood your case at all but this would be my fast solution

```
$vars = array('var1' => 'condition1', 'var2' => 'condition2', 'var3' => 'condition3');

foreach ($vars as $var => $condition) {
    if ($row[$condition] == 0) {
        $$var = $_POST[$var];
    } else {
        $$var = $_POST[$var . 'hidden'];
    }
}
```

save the vars and conditions in an array (the array structure can be different of course) and just loop through them

hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

PHP supports "variable variables", using a double dollar sign syntax. For example:

```
$var1 = 'foo';
$name = 'var1';

echo $$name; // prints "foo"
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

However, if you really have that many variables, it's probably better to store them in an array instead.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this:

```
$i=1;
while ($i<=20){
if($row['condition[$i]']==0) {
$var[$i] = $_POST['var[$i]'];
} else {
$var[$i] = $_POST['var[$i]hidden'];
}
$i++;
} // END OF YOUR WHILE LOOP
```

Comment: your code only get the value from 1-19 not 1-20 so change your operator on while loop from < to <=.

Answer (score 1):

DO the simple okay:

```
$var=Array();
for($i=1;$i<=20;$i++){
  if($row['condition'] == 0) //Value pulled from MySQL table {
     $var[$i] = $_POST['var'.$i]; //Value from a form field
  } else {
     $var[$i] = $_POST['var'.$i.'hidden']; //Value from a hidden field
  }
}
```

and access it by their index :

```
echo $var[1];
echo $var[2];
echo $var[3];
... // and etc
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `{` and `}`:

```
if($row['condition1'] == 0) $var1 = $_POST['var1']; //Value from a form field
else $var1 = $_POST['var1hidden']; //Value from a hidden field 
if($row['condition2'] == 0) $var2 = $_POST['var2']; //Value from a form field
else $var2 = $_POST['var2hidden']; //Value from a hidden field
```

You could do:

```
foreach ( $row as $key => $value ) {
  if($value == 0) $$var.($key+1) = $_POST['var'.($key+1)]; //Value from a form field
  else $$var.($key+1) = $_POST['var'.($key+1).'hidden']; //Value from a hidden field 
}
```

Comment: Removing curly braces is not a very good idea. It gets confusing if you have a lot of conditional statements. Also, this doesn't answer the OP's question. You'll still need to define and compare 20 variables. I don't think this is what the OP asked. *but I'd prefer not to have to copy it twenty times..*

Answer (score 0):

I think Amal is missing your $row var, and you can use a ternary operator for less code as follows:

```
for ($i=1; $i <= 20; $i++) { 
  $row['condition'.$i] == 0 ? ${'var'.$i} = $_POST['var'.$i] : ${'var'.$i} =    $_POST['var' . $i . 'hidden'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Chris i see you need this solution in order to fetch some POSTS vars.
My advice is to make sure that on your HTML code you will rename all your input box from "var1", "var2", "var3" etc.. to "var[]"

HTML SIDE EXAMPLE

```
<input type="text" name="var[]" >
<input type="text" name="var[]" >
<input type="text" name="var[]" >
<input type="text" name="var[]" >
<input type="text" name="varhidden[]" >
<input type="text" name="varhidden[]" >
<input type="text" name="varhidden[]" >
<input type="text" name="varhidden[]" >
```

PHP SIDE EXAMPLE

```
$vars = $_POST[ "var" ];
$vars_hidden = $_POST[ "varhidden" ];

$vars_result = array();

if( !empty( $vars ) ){
    for( $v = 0; $v < count( $vars ); $v++ ){

        if( isset( $vars[ $v ] ) ){
            $vars_result[ $v ] = $vars[ $v ];
        } elseif( isset( $vars_hidden[ $v ] ) ){
            $vars_result[ $v ] = $vars_hidden[ $v ];
        } else {
            $vars_result[ $v ] = NULL;
        }

    }
}
```

-->

?>